# Highcharts Treemap: opacity bug with 3 levels?

Tags: highcharts, opacity, treemap

today I noticed something strange with my treemap.
If you have 3 levels and you drill them down, then you go
one level up und you drive around with your mousecursor and then you
go on the top level, it looks something like that:
[Treemap Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFODb.jpg)

You can test it with the official Treemap-Demo, you only have to add

```
    series: [{
        ...
        opacity: 1.0,
        ...
    }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ks7qqaoz/

Is there any workaround because because with big treemaps this happens quite often!

thanks

Comment: It looks like it is caused by not resetting hover state of the point when the animation is turned on. I have not been able to reproduce the effect as on your image but I could see borders after drill up. You may try to disable animation http://jsfiddle.net/ks7qqaoz/1/ or wrap drillUp method with resetting  pointer http://jsfiddle.net/ks7qqaoz/2/ You can report it (with the steps to reproduce) as a bug here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Thanks, this should do it for now.